# Can I omit the word "it" and "she" from the following "as...as" sentences and still be correct?

Tags: grammar

Can I omit the word "it" and "she" from the following sentences and still be correct.

1- Everything may not be as neat and clean as (it) is being portrayed.

2- Kate is not as good as (she) is thought by others.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can

1. Everything may not be as neat and clean as someone is portraying.
2. Kate is not as good as others thought